# Will PutRecords resend data when network is terrible

Tags: aws-sdk-go

I send data to aws kinesis via PutRecords. And all the data is sent successfully.
  But some record is received twice in consumer side. I checked the sent data and received data, they are same.
  I think PutRecords will resend data when it doesn't receive response from kinesis server(response lost due to the terrible network station). But the data is receive by kinesis server.
  So, I get same record twice on the consumer side.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the SDK are you using? The SDK does not retry on timeouts. So I do not think that is the reason.

Whatever the reason may be for the duplicates, there is a good post about dealing with duplicates [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got reply form support team, The record may be stored in kineis server side but sdk return error due to bad network. My app will send record again due to the replied error. I need to add a primary key or unique index for each record. So that i can drop some record which has been received. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html#kinesis-record-processor-duplicates-producer Thanks a lot! Have a nice day!